# How to use a customized directory location for installing R packages

Tags: r, package

I am running Rstudio 0.97 with R 3.0.1 on Windows 8.1. I installed a lot of packages through Rstudio and they all went to "\R\R-3.0.1\library". Now I installed R 3.1.0 and set Rstudio to use the new version of R. But then I found the packages are all inaccessible from Rstudio.

How to make the packages in a shared folder so that the different versions of R on my PC can all use them?

I tried to use .libPaths("XXXX package sharefolder") to set a sharefolder to storing and installing new packages, it works in a session but when I restart Rstudio, the path is reset. Didn't work.

Comment: add `.libPaths("XXXX package sharefolder")` to your `.Rprofile`. http://www.statmethods.net/interface/customizing.html

Comment: Thanks! You can use that as an answer and I shall accept it!

Answer (score 1):

First, `mkdir ~/whatever-you-want` if necessary.

Second, add `R_LIBS_USER="~/whatever-you-want"` to `'~/.Renviron'`.

So, if you want to reuse `\R\R-3.0.1\library` as you mentioned, add `R_LIBS_USER="\R\R-3.0.1\library"` to your `'~/.Renviron'`. If you are using Windows, put the `.Renviron` in `C:\Users\<user-name>\`.

Hope it helps.