# R_LIBS_USER not being set despite user environment file

Tags: r

Using R 3.2.2 on Windows 7 without admin access to R installation directory, I have following line in `.Renviron` in my Documents folder.

```
R_LIBS_USER='~/R/win-library/3.2.2'
```

Once R starts up, I check the following environment variables:

```
> Sys.getenv(c("R_HOME", "R_ENVIRON", "R_ENVIRON_USER",
+ "R_PROFILE_USER", "R_LIBS_USER", "R_PROFILE"))
                                           R_HOME 
                         "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-32~1.2" 
                                        R_ENVIRON 
                                               "" 
                                   R_ENVIRON_USER 
                                               "" 
                                   R_PROFILE_USER 
                                               "" 
                                      R_LIBS_USER 
"C:\\Users\\cornma7\\Documents/R/win-library/3.2" 
                                        R_PROFILE 
                                               ""
```

The value of R_LIBS_USER is not a valid directory (expected path ending "3.2.2").  The installation's `Rprofile.site` file only has one line:

```
options(help_type="html")
```

Don't know why this doesn't work. My `.RProfile` file is currently blank and thus not overriding any environment variables.

Have tried placing `.Renviron` one directory up in C:\Users\username as suggested in [How to use a customized directory location for installing R packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23059737/how-to-use-a-customized-directory-location-for-installing-r-packages/23072963#23072963)